# Implementing TryFrom/TryInto trait (instead of From/Into)

Tags: rust, traits

I tried to "overload" a function using the `From` trait (so that it can accept a struct and a string):

```
pub struct Measurement {
    pub value: i16,
    pub unit: char,
}

impl From<&str> for Measurement {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Measurement {
        let value = s[0..s.len() - 1].parse::<i16>().unwrap();
        let unit = s.chars().last().unwrap();

        return Measurement { value, unit };
    }
}

pub fn print_measurement<T: Into<Measurement>>(value: T) {
    let m = value.into();
    println!("Measurement is {}{}", m.value, m.unit);
}

fn main() {
    print_measurement("40m");
    print_measurement(Measurement{value: 23, unit: 'g'});
}
```

As per [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa9d1531dfa3983df7be6631556fe0e1), this works as expected. However, since parsing of the string can fail, I wanted to use `try_into()`, instead of `into()`. So:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Measurement {
    pub value: i16,
    pub unit: char,
}

impl TryFrom<&str> for Measurement {
    type Error = String;

    fn try_from(s: &str) -> Result<Measurement, String> {
        let value = s[0..s.len() - 1].parse::<i16>();
        let unit = s.chars().last();
        match (value, unit) {
            (Ok(v), Some(u)) => Ok(Measurement { value: v, unit: u }),
            _ => Err("Invalid value or unit".to_string()),
        }
    }
}

pub fn try_print_measurement<T: TryInto<Measurement>>(value: T) {
    let m = value.try_into();
    match m {
        Ok(m) => println!("Measurement is {}{}", m.value, m.unit),
        Err(e) => println!("Error when parsing: {:?}", e),
    }
}

fn main() {
    try_print_measurement("4_0m"); // <-- this line should fail to parse
    try_print_measurement(Measurement{value: 23, unit: 'g'});
}
```

Questions:

1. Unfortunately, the above fails with `error[E0277]: '<T as TryInto<Measurement>>::Error' doesn't implement 'Debug'`. Why isn't the error type equal to `String` as specified, but rather `<T as TryInto<Measurement>>::Error`? And what does this error type mean?
2. Instead of `let m = value.try_into()` I tried `let m = Measurement::try_from(value)`. But this fails with `error[E0277]: the trait bound 'Measurement: From<T>' is not satisfied`, which seems odd as I call `try_from` (and not `from`). Why is that?
3. How would one correctly implement the `TryFrom` trait, so that the parsing errors can be dealt with as outlined?
4. Why do we need to bring `TryFrom` into scope via `use std::convert::TryFrom`, whereas the `From` trait does not require this?

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for the quick fix: `where <T as TryInto<Measurement>>::Error: std::fmt::Debug`. But I'd also like to understand why. Why is the error type of `try_into()` not just a `String` ? Since we have `type Error = String;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. associated type are still generic, why every implementation of `TryInto<Measurement>` would use `String` for `TryFrom::Error` ? Follow compiler hint. You could have an implementation for `impl TryFrom<i32> for Measurement` or whatever that use different associated type.

   ```rust
   pub fn try_print_measurement<T>(value: T)
   where
       T: TryInto<Measurement>,
       <T as TryInto<Measurement>>::Error: std::fmt::Debug,
   {
       let m = value.try_into();
       match m {
           Ok(m) => println!("Measurement is {}{}", m.value, m.unit),
           Err(e) => println!("Error when parsing: {:?}", e),
       }
   }
   ```
2. cause your bound is `TryInto<Measurement>` not `TryFrom<&str>`. [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html#impl-TryInto%3CU%3E) have blanked implementation when `T` implement `TryFrom`, not the opposite.
3. you did
4. cause Rust 2018 didn't include it in prelude, [Rust 2021 does](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html#additions-to-the-prelude)

Comment: Thank you. Just out of curiosity on point 2. Changing the bound to `T: TryFrom<&str>` and then using `let m = Measurement::try_from(value);` still causes `error[E0277]: the trait bound 'Measurement: From<T>' is not satisfied`. Why is that?

Comment: @Phil-ZXX https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f35088683cfafa452630de84cd4ba83d but it's not recommand tryinto bound are better

Comment: Thank you! Good to know the syntax in any case

Comment: @Stargateur The playground link does not seem to work anymore. Could you elaborate why `the trait bound 'Measurement: From<T>' is not satisfied` still occurs after changing the bound to `T: TryFrom<&str>`? I'm dealing with a similar problem.